# Injecting newline + tab in a string every 15 characters but without cutting words

Tags: c#, regex

I would like to create a csharp function for 'injecting' a **new line** (\r\n) + a **tab** (\t) character in a string every 15 characters but without cuttings words.

So for example for this string:

```
I whish you a merry Christmas and a happy new year.
```

The result should be:

```
I whish you a 
merry Christmas 
and a happy new 
year.
```

I don't see how to proceed. It seems difficult to me to achieve. I don't know where to start, maybe with regular expression but I really don't.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you don't know whether regex is relevant to your question, why did you tag it so?

Comment: `/(.{15})/\1\r\n/`, the "not cutting words" is left as an exercise to the op.

Comment: Surely a very naive implementation would be to start at the start of your sentence and check to see if the 15th character is a space. if it is you split there, otherwise you count back until you find one. Then you just repeat? i.e. you should be able to implement a potentially sub-optimal solution and then improve from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too hot with C# regex, so it may not be too easy to make dot-match-newline.  In Ruby this is default behavior and in PHP the `s` modifier enables it.  But if we match `.{1,15}` followed by whitespace, it will match the first fifteen characters and than backtrack until its at a full word.  We can then replace with our capture group and `\r\n\t`:

```
(.{1,15})(?:\s+|$)
\1\r\n\t
```

---

```
(          (?# start capture group)
  .{1,15}  (?# match 1-15 characters)
)          (?# end capture group)
(?:        (?# start non-capture group)
  \s+      (?# match 1+ whitespace characters)
 |         (?# OR)
  $        (?# match the end of the string)
)          (?# end non-capture group)
```

Demo: [Regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sJ4oD3)

Comment: It looks like [`RegexOptions.Singleline`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx) does the same as the `s` modifier in my example..hopefully this helps

Comment: C# code: `Regex.Replace("I whish you a merry Christmas and a happy new year.", @"(.{0,15})\s+", @"$1\r\n\t")`

Comment: Why add the `\t` at the end of the replacement? It seems to make lines 2-4 indented.

Comment: @gunr2171 I was basing it off OP: *`'injecting' a new line (\r\n) + a tab (\t) character`* (not sure though, since his example result doesn't have the tab character)

Comment: Your solution is nearly good except it should count 15 characters and reset this counter on each newline. Example with this string: 'This is the world as it should be'. Try copy/paste this string in your demo and you'll see that the 'be' word is placed on a new line. That's the problem. Hope you understand me.

Comment: @Bronzato, good catch -- that's because there is no whitespace at the end of the string...so I made it match whitespace OR the end of the string (`$`).  Also, I changed `.{0,15}` to `.{1,15}` so we don't match the end of the string as "15 characters".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little console application. As Daniel Kelley commented it's quite naive.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var input = "I whish you a merry Christmas and a happy new year.";
        var list = new List<string>();
        var temp = 0;
        var index = 15;

        while (true)
        {
            if (input[index] == ' ')
            {
                list.Add(input.Substring(temp, 15));
                temp = index + 1;
            }
            else
            {
                for (var j = index; j > 0; j--)
                {
                    if (input[j] == ' ')
                    {
                        list.Add(input.Substring(temp, j - temp));
                        index = temp = j;
                        temp++;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            index += 16;

            if (index >= input.Count() - 1)
            {
                list.Add(input.Substring(temp, input.Length - 1 - temp));
                break;
            }
        }

        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        list.ForEach(str => sb.Append(str + "\r\n\t"));
        Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```